# Is there a way to change the values of the CharacterJoint component (eg. hightwistlimit) in a script in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, physics, ragdoll

I want to change the various joint angles of the characterjoint with a script in runtime. But I didn't find a way to access the angles via script.

I found the scripting API for characterjoints here:https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CharacterJoint.html
But I'm still not sure, for example how to change the swingLimit1 value of a specific characterjoint.

I'm using this code to call the functions of a characterjoint but "jnt" doesn't have any of those functions.

CharacterJoint[] jnts;

```
    void Start()
    {
        jnts = GetComponentsInChildren<CharacterJoint>();    
    }

    void Update()
    {
        foreach (Joint jnt in jnts)
        {
            jnt.
        }
    }
```

Comment: Looks like you can just acquire the particular `CharacterJoint` component (e.g. `GetComponent<CharacterJoint>()`), then modify those values... Am I missing something here? :D

Comment: I thought it was that simple too! I'm trying to modify the values of CharacterJoint but Unity can't find those functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh god I feel like an idiot.
The problem was I used "Joint" instead of "CharacterJoint" in the foreach loop.
This is the correct version:

```
void Update()
    {
        foreach (CharacterJoint jnt in jnts)
        {
            jnt.swing1Limit
        }
    }
```

Thanks for the help!